# How to find the words that are present in all input strings with Python?

Tags: python, text, keyword, words

In python is there anyway of comparing two different lines of text to see if two or more words match?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use sets and compute the intersection:

```
>>> a = "one two three"
>>> b = "one three four"
>>> set(a.split()) & set(b.split())
set(['three', 'one'])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split each of the lines to get the list of words that are present. Then compare the lists to check for common words.

```
def get_common_words_count(str1, str2):
    list1 = str1.split()
    list2 = str2.split()
    c = 0
    for word in list1:
        try:
            list2.index(word)
            c += 1
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return c

print get_common_words_count('this is the first', 'and this is the second')
```